# For Loop in Recursive Function breaking without delivering result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, recursion, angular-controller

Currently, I am using a recursive function within an existing angular controller to generate an array of indices based upon a tree structure, which is creating a "branch" to the specified target value. The intention of the function is to recursively check the values of a deeply nested object and loop through arrays as they may appear. The function works until it finds the target node and matches it. On the return call, which based upon what I know, should loop back up into the for loop. Instead, it exits the function and returns `undefined`. I did notice that the error thrown is generated by Angular, and is as follows.

```
angular.js:13236 ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at questionsController.self.findIndex (questions-controller.js:724)
    at questionsController.self.findIndex (questions-controller.js:734)
    at questionsController.self.findIndex (questions-controller.js:724)
    at questionsController.self.addQuestions (questions-controller.js:711)      
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14086), <anonymous>:4:262)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15076)
    at callback (angular.js:24546)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16820)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16920)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:24551)
```

The function is as follows:

```
self.findIndex = function (map, target, arr, index) {
        if (map instanceof Array) {
            for (var x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
                var newArr = arr.slice();
                newArr.push(x);
                result = self.findIndex(map[x], target, newArr, x);
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        } else if (map instanceof Object) {
            if (map.id == target.id) {
                return arr;
            }
            else if (map.questions && map.questions.length > 0) {
                return result = self.findIndex(map.questions, target, arr, index);
            }
        }
        return [];
    };
```

The data model is as follows:

```
[
  {
     id: 1,
     name: 'foo',
     questions: [
        {
         id: 2,
         name: 'bar',
         questions: []
        }
     ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'foobar',
    questions: [
       {
        id: 4,
        name: 'barfoo',
        questions: [
           {
             id: 5,
             name: 'foobarfoo',
             questions: []
           },
           {
             id: 6,
             name: 'barfoobar',
             questions: []
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Please let me know if any additional info regarding the question might help provide clarity.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you use **[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** to iterate your arrays instead of a counting loop because `.forEach()` doesn't have a counter and makes accessing the array elements much cleaner.

Comment: You need to define `result` e.g. with `var` or `let`. Also `return result = ...` is not necessary, just write `return ...`.

Comment: NB: You are not using the `index` parameter, so just ditch it. If you declare `result`, the function works.

Comment: Oh my, that did it! Thank you for the quick response, I was hoping that it would be something along these lines, fear that I've been looking at this code for far too many minutes today. Thank you for the correction and code recommendations, is there any way for me to up-vote your answers? This is my first post to the Stack.